# Does go-ethereum/whisper provides any kind of Public Key Server to obtain other nodes' public key

Tags: whisper

For example [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org) has a Public Key Server, where users able to obtain other users public-keys by using a key ID.

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110146/179928:

> OpenPGP User IDs
>
> User IDs in OpenPGP are used to connect keys to entities like names
> and e-mail addresses. These are used to search for keys on key
> servers, and matching them to users/e-mail addresses.

```
node_a> gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com    --send-keys EFA2F330
node_b> gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EFA2F330
```

---

**=>** Does `go-ethereum` provides this approach for `Whisper` where key-ids might be the user's Ethereum address in order to obtain other geth nodes' public key for `Whisper`?

[Here:](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.geth.html?highlight=whisper#web3.geth.txpool.Shh.post)

> `targetPeer (optional)`: Peer ID (for peer-to-peer message only).

Than is actual from this [comment](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18003#issuecomment-505398719):

> It is indeed be the enode of your target peer. See https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/whisper/whisperv6/api.go#L294.

Overall, if I use `enode` as alternative to public-key, which is much larger string than the public key itself.

Comment: Have you tried posting in the Geth Discord (linked on https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) ?

Comment: I did one week ago, but no one responded me back and I think no one ever will. @eth

Comment: It looks like the answer to this is No. I don't know much about Whisper and other idea to try is posting on Ethereum Reddit in rare chance someone wants to set up a server.

Comment: @eth: Thanks. I believe Whisper has a great potention but it seems like an abonden project. I have posted the idea into Ethereum Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/heccn2/does_goethereumwhisper_provides_any_kind_of/). I will work on the set up a server for this and if I can I will let you know.